# CSS - Make child div have same padding as parent div

Tags: html, css, padding

I use the following format:

```
body: margin x%
.parent: padding y%
    .child: some width, exact above padding
```

Body has a `margin` of x percent. Inside, there is a parent `div` that has a y percent `padding`. And a child `div` of some width that I am trying to make it have the exact same `padding` as the parent. Any suggestions without using javascript?

Comment: A simple solution would be to have a class with the padding that you want and apply the class to both the parent and child and any other area that you want it applied to.
How are you laying our your HTML and are you able to change the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Can you work with vw instead of %? The viewport width is always the same for any parent and child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding: inherit;` for child elements. A child element will get the padding from a parent div.

Comment: @darkchampionz are you sure it works? it doesn't for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tzgq4xb9/

Comment: @darkchampionz check this https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/NWWdLYW

Comment: @NehaSharma trying to help is a good thing but insisting using wrong information is not.

Comment: @NehaSharma I _am_ helping, by pointing out that what you suggest as a solution, _isn’t_ actually one. _You_ changed the parameters here, by using a different unit than what the question was about to begin with. And as was already pointed out, when we change it to percentages in your example, it gives values that are only “close”, but not the _exact_ same, as the question required.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate this relying on `vw` unit. The padding consider the width of the parent to get computed so the padding of the `parent` element will be `width of viewport - margin of the body = width of the body`. We can consider `calc()` to obtain the padding and use the same for the child.

Here is an example where I consider `10%` padding and `5%` margin on the parent. The only drawback of this method is the width of scroll bar that is considered in the calculation that's why I call it an *approximation*

```css
.parent {
  padding:calc((100vw - 2*0.05*100vw)*0.1);
  border:1px solid;
}
.percentage {
  padding:10%;
}
.child {
  padding:calc((100vw - 2*0.05*100vw)*0.1);
  border:1px solid;
}

body {
  margin:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent percentage">
  <div class="child">
    some content here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    some content here
  </div>
</div>
```